# Extremely slow code when using big array sizes

Tags: java, arrays, memory

I have a program that runs extremely slow when using big array numbers.

I use an `int[3000][3000]`, a `String[27000]`, and a `String[5000]` array in the final code. This code takes forever to run. Could this be because the arrays take too much space?

Comment: what part is slow? Is it the initialization, or is program taking a long to process the array contents?

Comment: The initialization is taking forever.

Comment: Look for nested loops on your `int[3000][3000]` Two nested loops would be fine, but a third one would kill performance.

Comment: It is more likely an issue with your algorithms

Comment: Please include a representative example of the code you are using.

Comment: In the `int[3000][3000]` I have an if-statement inside a for loop inside a for loop.

Comment: Did you verify your assumption with a profiler? Also you should quantify "extremely slow".

Comment: Show the code for the initialisation.

Comment: voting to close because there is no description or code examples of the methods used upon the datatypes shown, no description of what "slow" means and no idea of what alternative techniques are being asked for

Comment: maybe use a more memory efficient data structure like a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a good deal on the complexity of your algorithms on which you are manipulating the data.  with. This determines how much time it will take as you start throwing more data in it (by making the arrays larger and larger).If you are just iterating through the data, then it would be on the order of O(n), meaning it would be proportional to the amount of data give; so if you doubled the length of you arrays, it would take twice as long to execute your program. If you were, say , comparing every element with the other, it would mean it would be on the order of O(n^2), so if you doubled the length of your arrays, it would take around four times longer to process them.

You would have to post your program for us to have any idea if your algorithm is just to complex for your computer to handle.

see also: [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions)

Answer (score -3):

Many Factors :

1. Processor  processing Speed.
2. Memory allocation
3. 3000*3000*4 bytes = 36* 10.00.000 bytes = 338 MB
4. Use list

Comment: 3k*3k*4 bytes are 35 mb. And you can't be serious with this answer.

Comment: Speaking of using list (which really would not help improving the speed for the OP BTW), I edited your answer to actually use one.